# Почему возникает ошибка: “ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1” в Google Colab при попытке клонировать репозиторий?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, pip

Я попытался клонировать репозиторий с помощью pip себе в Google Colab c помощью команды:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/adityatb/noise-reduction-using-rnn.git
```

И получил такой вывод:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/adityatb/noise-reduction-using-rnn.git
Cloning https://github.com/adityatb/noise-reduction-using-rnn.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-ka8brgnj
<b>ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.</b>
```

Пробовал:

1. Поставить ! перед pip.
2. Обновить pip.
3. Обновить setuptools.
   Ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто: в репозитории нет файла `setup.py` поэтому *pip* не может его установить. Нужно руками копировать файлы к себе в папку. Или проанализировать репозиторий и самому написать данный файл.